# Insert Image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert a image with css. In Chrome it is diplayed as desired.

***CSS:***

```
.logo {
    content: url("../Icons/logo.png");
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<span class="logo pull-right"></span>
```

But in Firefox it is not inserted. I have tried to use the :before pseudo class. But the size of the image should also be considered. With the pseudo class the image is not resized to desired dimensions.

Is there a better CSS method to insert images?

regards,
Marko

## Update

**My Logo Image is larger then the area where it is placed!**

Here is a fiddle ...

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/URu57/

Comment: Why not use `background-image`?

Comment: Add `display:block` to `.logo`. The span isn't doing anything with `width` & `height` because it's (by default) set to `display:inline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to set it as a `background` instead of `content`, check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kT7L6/1/):

```
.logo {
    background: url("http://goo.gl/OJhO2s") no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px 250px;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}
```

And giving it an specific `width` and `height` along with the `block` display property (you may also want to use a `div` for this instead of a span).

Comment: With your method the image is not resized.

Comment: Of course you should need to provide an image of the correct size. Or use the `background-size` property (check my updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Can try this `:before` or `:after`,

```
.logo:before {
   content: url("../Icons/logo.png");
   width: auto;
   height: 50px;
   margin-top: 35px;
   margin-bottom: 65px
 }
```

instead of

```
.logo {
  ...
 }
```

Ref: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore)

Comment: I believe you have an extra space in front of the semicolon - `.logo:before`

Comment: I have added an fiddle with the before pseudo class.

Comment: Loading larger images is not recommended in practice, better way to optimize the image, it avoid the server performance and bandwidth etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

**CSS:**

```
.logo {
    backgroud: url("../Icons/logo.png") no-repeat;
    width: auto; / * specify the width */
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}
```

Comment: `.logo {
    background: url("../Icons/logo.png") no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}`

With the code above nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah:
Best method, use

```
background: url("/Icons/logo.png") [parameters];
```